# SQL Concat , php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, concatenation

This is my code

```
$this->db->select('*, CONCAT(left(card_id, 1 ), right(card_id, 6 )) AS character_id', FALSE);
```

Error : 
An Error Was Encountered

```
Unknown column '1' in 'field list'
```

Please help me with this!!!

Comment: are you getting the error from mysql or from codeigniter's sql generator?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you forgot to specify your tablename.

Please replace [tablename] with the name of your table:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *, CONCAT(left(card_id, 1 ), right(card_id, 6 )) AS character_id FROM [tablename]');
```

or:

```
$this->db->select("*, CONCAT(left(card_id, 1 ), right(card_id, 6 )) AS character_id");
$this->db->from("[tablename]");
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$this->db->select("*, CONCAT(left(card_id, 1 ), right(card_id, 6 )) AS character_id",FALSE);
$this->db->from("table");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```